# How to create a structured catalog?

Tags: craft3

help me figure it out. I need to create a structured directory. So that there are categories nested inside each other. I created the "Examples" section. According to the idea, there should be other categories in the "Examples" category, within which there should also be other categories.

```
That is, like this:
- Examples
-- Geometry
--- First class
--- Second class
--- Third grade
```

There are two questions:

1. How to organize such a structure in the administrative system? Should I create two partitions? One with the name "News" and the second with the name "News Categories"? And using the "Entries" field to link these two sections?
2. I want the content of the selected category on the site to open at this URL: "site.com/examples/geometry/first_klass /" I.e. each category is present in the URL.

Maybe my idea is fundamentally wrong. Please tell me the most correct and logical solution.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for the [Structure](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/entries.html#structures) section type! Structures allow you to manually nest and order entries.

A bit further down that documentation page, you’ll find [a section about URIs](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/entries.html#entry-uri-formats)—generally, if you want entries in a structure to have nested URLs, you would use a URI format like this:

```
{parent.uri ?? 'examples'}/{slug}
```

…which handles the scheme you’re describing, recursively!

For example:

- The top-level “Geometry” entry (with slug `geometry`) would get a URI of `examples/geometry` because it has no parent.
- Nesting “First Class” (with slug `first-class`) under “Geometry” would get a URI of `examples/geometry/first-class` because it *does* have a parent, and the parent’s URI (including `examples`) is used instead of the default (`examples`).